# Combining tables on the same sheet in excel

Tags: excel

So i have a spreadsheet where i keep track of time for the day with summary at the end using countif to summarise my day in activities.

I have 7 of these 'summary' - 1 for each day of the week.
I want to combine all of these tables into 1 on the same sheet so that i can make a pivot table using them.

I have tried the following:

- 'Vstack' which works really nicely but then I cannot transform that into a table. Is there anyone who knows how to do that?
- Consolidate function on the data tab - but it wants to export it to a new sheet for it to be dynamic but unfortunately i cannot use that.

I am not that familiar with power query.

Comment: Use PowerQuery to combine them.

Comment: Okay cool, thank you. Will PowerQuery auto be created when i copy my weekly template sheet to the new sheet so that the tables on the new sheet also combine with PowerQuery?

Comment: As mentioned, above, use `Power Query` in current channel `PQ` can take arrays to create tables .

Comment: No, PQ won't be auto generated if you copy the sheet.

Comment: Please share your attempts in detail (e.g. the `VSTACK` formula). *"when i copy my weekly template sheet to the new sheet"* looks like relevant information. Add a detailed description of what it means to your post.